# Why are my Java and command line SHA256 outputs different?

Tags: java, sha256

I'm getting different outputs from hashing a string on the command line vs. in Java on Android.  I'm sure I'm doing something wrong, but I don't see what.

Command line:

```
kevin@aphrodite:~$ echo derp | sha256sum
ee673d13de31533a375b41d9e57731d9bb4dbddbd6c1d2364f15be40fd783346  -
```

Java:

```
final String plaintext = "derp";
final MessageDigest md;
try {
    md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
/* SHA-256 should be supported on all devices. */
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
final String inputHash = bytesToHex(md.digest(plaintext.getBytes()));
Log.debug(TAG, "input hash: " + inputHash);
```

Java output:

```
10-05 13:32:57.412: D/Config(12082): input hash: 3f4146a1d0b5dac26562ff7dc6248573f4e996cf764a0f517318ff398dcfa792
```

Here's the `bytesToHex(...)` method, which I found in another Q&A.  I confirmed that it's doing the right thing by logging `Integer.toHexString(b)` for each `b`.

```
private static final char[] hexDigit = "0123456789abcdef".toCharArray();

private static String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
    char[] hexChars = new char[bytes.length * 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; ++i) {
        int b = bytes[i] & 0xFF;
        hexChars[i * 2] = hexDigit[b >>> 4];
        hexChars[i * 2 + 1] = hexDigit[b & 0x0F];
    }
    return new String(hexChars);
}
```

Comment: Since the answer has already been established (`\n` in echo), might I also suggest that you can supplant your custom `bytesToHex()` in favor of [`DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(byte[] val)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.html)

Comment: @Keith That doesn't exist in Android.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because `echo` includes a trailing new-line. You can use

```
echo -n derp | sha256sum
```

**or** add `\n` to your `plaintext` like

```
final String plaintext = "derp\n";
```